# Will crafted EXPCalibur sword also have no repairs/low durability?

Tags: dying-light

I found the EXPCalibur on the rock and also got the blueprint. I was shocked to see the one I picked up had only 8 durability and no repairs. Before realizing it I had upgraded it with a number of pretty good upgrades.

If I craft my own from the blueprint will it also be just as gimmicky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, crafting it results in the same low durability, plus requires Bolter Tissue to make it.  I found this video showing the sword's attributes at 04:42 in:

Comment: The caveat is that, even when broken, the sword is still powerful enough to be useful, you can still use the charge attack, and you will also detect zombies near you.